# Разбить с помощью метода split() строку с двоичным числом на октеты?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть двоичное число:

```
String s = "10000000001000000000101000000001"
```

Можно ли с помощью метода `split()` разбить его на октеты?

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("10000000001000000000101000000001".split(/(?!^)(?=(?:.{8})+$)/))
```

Answer (score 0):

Сплит тут подходит плохо... Регулярка по факту не очень быстрая.
Почему не написать простой метод? Что-то типа этого:

```
private String[] divideBy (String numb, int digitNumb){
    final String[]result = new String[numb.length()/digitNumb];
    for (int i = 0; i < numb.length()/digitNumb; i++) {
        result[i] = numb.substring(i*digitNumb, i*digitNumb+digitNumb);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Передаете первым аргументом свое число в стринге, а во втором количество цифр, на которое нужно поделить (по условию это 8, но можно поделить на любое количество) и получаете обычный массив.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
String s = "10000000001000000000101000000001";
String[] octets = s.split("(?<=\\G.{8})");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(octets));
// = [10000000, 00100000, 00001010, 00000001]
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/KjY8CY).

Шаблон `(?<=\G.{8})` представляет собой блок предварительного просмотра назад и находит позицию после любых первых восьми символов, а потом ещё после восьми и так далее.